# how to get specific int value from string in java [122356]

Tags: java

How to get all int value from a string value, e.g. [122356].
I tried this:

```
Query query=s.createQuery("select pid from Patient where emailid=? ");

String pid = query.setParameter(0, email).list().toString();
char abc= pid.charAt(1);
int patientid=Character.getNumericValue(abc);
```

Comment: What type is `Query`? Generally speaking, the proper way to do this is to tell the query to return an `Integer`.

Comment: Do you want the full integer value of the `String` or so you want a specific cypher of the number that is represented by a `String`? You are using `char abc = pid.charAt(1);`, that's why I ask...

Comment: yes i want full integer value. But i don't find any way that's why i try this.

Comment: If `pid` has always the pattern `[d+]`, thus `'['` is the first character and `']'` is the last character and the digits are in between. you can use: `Integer.parseInt(pid.substring(1, pid.length() - 1));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do :

```
int num = Integer.parseInt("[122356]".replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));
```

Here we first replace all occurences of `[` and `]` with empty space and then parse the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an int value from a string value by using parseInt, like so:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(string_of_number);
```

You should validate the value that num has after this operation. You can read about it here: [parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: [12345] how to get all the value except [ ]

Comment: if the brackets are part of the string, you will not get them when you parse it with parseInt. Try it, and if you have any problems with it, let me know. @user9040086

Comment: how can i substring and get all the value @Xeo28

Comment: You could use replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "") on the string before parsing it. @user9040086
Nicholas K's answer includes the complete command.

Answer (score 0):

`list()` might return more than one record,you need to get the specify record,and it better to use `Integer.parseInt()` get int value

```
Query query=s.createQuery("select pid from Patient where emailid=? ");

//get value from the first record
String pid = query.setParameter(0, email).list().get(0).toString();
char abc= pid.charAt(1);
int patientid=Character.getNumericValue(abc);
//better to use this get int
//int patientid=Integer.parseInt(abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse String back to Integer;

```
int num = Integer.parseInt("122356");
```

Comment: [12345] how to get all the value except [ ]

Answer (score 0):

In case you know that the `String` representation of your number is enclosed in brackets, then you have to remove them before parsing. You can do it like this:

```
// replace brackets with an empty String, needs two operations due to two different brackets
String numberInBrackets = "[123456]";
String numberWithoutBrackets = numberInBrackets.replace("[", "");
String numberWithoutBrackets = numberWithoutBrackets.replace("]", "");
int number = Integer.parseInt(numberWithoutBrackets);
```

Alternatively, you cut them off using `String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`:

```
// cut off the trailing and leading characters of the String
String numberInBrackets = "[123456]";
String numberWithoutBrackets = numberInBrackets.substring(1, numberInBrackets.length() - 1);
```

If the `String` just contains cyphers, then just do

```
String number = "123456";
int number = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 ways( one of them is pointed by Nicolas K. ) which is, at least for me, the most appropriate here, but you could use also something like this, assuming that the string is in the pattern [int].

```
 int number = Integer.parseInt(yourData.substring (1, yourData.lastIndexOf(']')));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for cut "[" and "]".

Thank you .

Query q = s.createQuery(" select profileid  from Userprofile  where emailid=?");

```
    String profileid = q.setParameter(0, email).list().toString();
    int start = 0; // '(' position in string
    int end = 0; // ')' position in string
    for (int i = 0; i < profileid.length(); i++) {
        if (profileid.charAt(i) == '[') // Looking for '(' position in string
        {
            start = i;
        } else if (profileid.charAt(i) == ']') // Looking for ')' position in  string
        {
            end = i;
        }
    }
    String number = profileid.substring(start + 1, end);

    int pkst = Integer.parseInt(number);
    System.out.println("your number is :" + number);
```